# redirect part of output to user input

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I need to execute a command line tool within a shell script that requires user input. Usually, i would write something like:

```
echo $input | command
```

however, `$input` must be read from the standard error of `command` which I'm able to get e. g. using:

```
input=$(command 2>&1 > /dev/null | awk '/some.*regexp$/ {print $2}')
```

But I don't want to execute the command twice (once for extracting/saving the content of `$input` and once for feeding `command` with that input).

So, how can i get around that circular dependency and combine these two things to a single bash call with only one execution of `command`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `command > /dev/null 2>&1` sends all to /dev/null, but `command 2>&1 > /dev/null` only sends the standard output to /dev/null while standard error is redirected to whereever standard out was originally pointing before being redirected to /dev/null (i think)

Comment: Yep your right.